# Ports open only on specific event

Tags: windows, firewall, port-forwarding, netsh

I've recently opened some ports (8080, 2223, 2224) to open a sftp server and a webserver-type fileserver. However I've been running into issues and haven't found a single solution since.

The problem is as follows (I use Windows 10 professional):
I port forwarded the ports on my router (using my static IP) on TCP/UDP and added the ports to go through my firewall. Then when I try to connect to the server the connection times out. When running `netstat -aon` port 8080 appears to be ESTABLISHED on my static IP address, not port 2223/2224. However, 8080,2223,2224 are all LISTENING on the 0.0.0.0 address.

I don't have a double NAT, my ISP is not blocking the ports (I called them), I've tried adding my static IP to the DHCP range, I've added the ports using `netsh`, I've restarted the router, restarted my PC, checked the firmware and still no luck.

There is however one thing that worked up until now and that is by going to the [http://portquiz.net:{PORT}/](http://portquiz.net:%7BPORT%7D/) website. Whenever I then choose port 8080 or 2223/2224 the port opens for around 10 minutes and then closes. I've looked at how the website works and it uses IPtables for Ubuntu, which I know nothing about.

Does someone have any other idea on why this website suddenly opened my port for 10 minutes (and perhaps a permanent solution?)

edit: I have port forwarded ports 29132,29133 around 6 years ago and have been running a server on those ever since, they have always worked without fail. One additional piece of information I can give is that the ISP I used to be with got bought over by another ISP (Delta, from the Netherlands) some 3 years back.

Kind regards